# Stage parallel task scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to call multiple stages in parallel and using scripted pipeline. Got few examples but either were of Declarative pipeline or using parallel task in a stage.
Can anyone share link or reference which I can check for the same?

Aman

Comment: Somebody voted to close your question, probably you asked for a link. Probably everything would be fine (according to the "rules" here), when you ask for the "how" (aka code).

Comment: running a single stage with parallel block inside is better, since Jenkins UI show each stage as a block on the job page. moreover, stages should be consistent to maintain correct job history.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
stage("single step before") {
    echo "this is a single step before"
}

stage("parallel tasks") {
    parallel 'pipe1': {
        stage("parallel 1"){
            echo "pipe1: this is parallel 1"
        }
        stage("parallel 2"){
            echo "pipe1: this is parallel 2"
        }
        stage("parallel 3"){
            echo "pipe1: this is parallel 3"
        }
    }, 'parallel 4': {
        echo "pipe2: this is parallel 4"
    }
}
```

stage("single step after") {
echo "this is a single step after"
}